# Processes adapted to time changes

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis, stopping-times

I have a question regarding a passage in Chapter X of "Calcul Stochastique et Problèmes de Martingales"J.Jacod(1979). In (10.13) they define an adapted process $X$ to the time change $\tau(t)$  as a process that is constant on the interval $[\tau_{t-},\tau_t]$ (see also Lemma 10.14).

I don't really understand what this means(my French is not that good so it might be possible that I don't understand what that definition means).
I can see how this holds true for a time change driven by a continuous process, however if the time change has jumps, what would that condition imply?

Thank you .

**Edit**

For $\tau_t=\inf\{s: C_s<t\}$, where $C_t$ is an increasing process.

Def. 10.13

On dit qu'un processus $X$ est adapté au changement de temps $\tau$ si $X$ est constant sur chaque intervalle $[\tau_{t-},\tau_t]$.

Lemme 10.14

Il y a équivalence entre :

i) X est adapté a $\tau$;

ii) $X_{u\wedge\tau(\infty)}=X_{\tau(C_u)}$ pour tout $u\in \mathbb{R}_{+}$;

iii) $X$ est constant sur chaque intervalle $[u,v]$ tel que $C_u=C_{v-}<\infty$.

Edit for translation:

Definition 10.13 :

A process $X$ is said to be adapted to a time change $\tau$ if $X$ is constant over each interval of the form  $[\tau_{t-},\tau_t]$.

Lemma 10.14 :

The following three assertions are equivalent :

i) X is adapted to $\tau$;

ii) $X_{u\wedge\tau(\infty)}=X_{\tau(C_u)}$, $\forall u\in \mathbb{R}_{+}$;

iii)$X$ is constant on each interval $[u,v]$ such that $C_u=C_{v-}<\infty$.

Comment: Please make your question self-contained (e.g. add (10.13), Lemma 10.14).

Comment: @ KAT: I have added a translation for the definition and the lemma (I am french so I hope I got it right). Best regards.

Comment: @TheBridge Thank you. I was understanding the French in the same way, so I guess the problem is one of content and not the language.

Comment: @KAT: You are welcome but what is your question really ? I means what do you specifically don't understand about this definition (and the lemma giving equivalent criteria for this property) ?

Comment: What I don't understand is what that condition implies for a time change that moves by jumps. From iii) above this implies that if $C_t$ is a jump process the process X is constant where $C_t$ is constant and only jumps at the points where $C_t$ jumps. Is that what the definition implies? If so that seems quite limiting!

Comment: @KAT As far as I can tell, not necessarily. A jump process can jump infinitely many times in any finite interval (e.g infinite activity increasing Levy processes) so that iii) is a void statement and does not give a real "constraint" on X.